# Объявление и определение переменной

Tags: c++, variable

Имеем файл
***ini.h***

```
int n;
```

А также
***ini.cpp***

```
n = 5;
```

Получаю ошибку: **это объявление не содержит класс хранения или спецификатор типа**

если сделать так

***ini.h***

```
int n = 5;
```

***main.cpp***

```
include "ini.h"

int main()
{
 cout<<n;
}
```

Получаю ошибку: **int n уже определено в ini.obj**

Как же определить переменную в отдельном файле

Comment: Добавьте слово extern перед int в хедере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `ini.cpp` вы что, просто пишете `n = 5;`? Без указания типа, не в функции?

Понятно, что такой фокус не работает — это и не объявление и не определение (нет типа).

Вообще-то использование глобальных переменных — это плохо... Но если уж вам надо ну просто позарез, да еще и в разных файлах...

**ini.h**

```
extern int n;
```

Сие слово — `extern` — поясняет компилятору, что это просто объявление, а определение будет дано где-то в другом месте. Просто, так сказать, "учти — если встретишь переменную `n` — то это переменная типа `int`".

**ini.cpp**

```
int n = 5;
```

**main.cpp**

```
// Как у вас и написано
```

Comment: наверное уместно объяснение  роли ключевого слова extern

Comment: @ARHovsepyan OK, сейчас добавлю.